# Error when trying to update a row with a random value

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to update each row in a table with data from a random row from another table. Here is the SQL I am currently using:

```
SELECT Data, RowNumber FROM SampleData

SELECT FLOOR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 2147483647.0 * 3 + 1) FROM Name

UPDATE Name SET Surname = (SELECT Data FROM SampleData WHERE RowNumber = FLOOR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 2147483647.0 * 3 + 1))
```

And here are the results I'm getting:

```
Smith   1
Hunt    2
Jones   3

2
2
3
2
1
3
2
.... continues with a random number between 1 and 3 for each row in the Name table

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

So my question is why does the SELECT statement produce a single random number per row where the UPDATE sub-query seems to return multiple rows. I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP1 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: have a look to this query SELECT Nr,Count(*)  from
(
Select FLOOR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 2147483647.0 * 3 + 1) as Nr
FROM Name
) a   
Group by nr 
Having Count(*)>1

Comment: Not quite sure what that's meant to show me. The result for that is 3 rows that show that 1, 2 and 3 are returned roughly a third of the time each. But that's exactly what I would have expected

Comment: You are assigning a set or results to a single field http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3894/8 you coud use e.g. `SELECT TOP 1 Data FROM SampleData .......`

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how that helps. I'm am trying to update the Surname column in the Name table with a random value from the SampleData table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update a field with a set of data, this leads to the described error.

Create a temporary mapping table and update name form the join between ID of name and *"random"* ID of SampleDate

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eca7/1)

```
SELECT ID,FLOOR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 2147483647.0 * 3 + 1) as RN
Into #tmp
FROM Name

Update Name set SurName=Data 
from #tmp
join SampleData sd on sd.RowNumber=#tmp.rn
where #tmp.ID=Name.ID

Select * from Name
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works perfectly. I'm still at a loss to understand why my original query didn't work though

Comment: The output of your second query deliveres many items, surname can only take one. You are trying in your third query to set all names to all result`s` of the subquery. There is no automatic for spread the result on names.